# QGIS raster calculator not keeping each pixel with 1 byte?

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I have a raster where 1 pixel = 1 byte. I want to change every value different than zero to 1, transforming a gray scale into black & white. I think the expression should be:

```
"my_raster@1" > 0
```

The output format is GeoTIFF. It works, but the final size is four times bigger than the uncompressed GeoTIFF (each pixel is using a 32-bit integer, when it should use a 8-bit, as in the original).

How to solve this?

I also noted that the values became 1 and nan, instead of 1 and 0.

Why doesn't it save a compressed TIFF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raster Calculator in the raster menu is great for convenience but you don't have much control over the output as you have foud.  In your case it is assuming zero == null and defaults to 32 bits to be safe for all outputs.

You have two options.  One is to use [gdalwarp](https://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) (go `Raster->Projections->warp`) on your existing output to reduce the pixel depth and fix the nudata issue.  Alternatively, use the Raster Calculator in the processing tool box and redo your calculation (go: `Processing toolbar -> GDAL/OGR -> [GDAL]Miscellaneous -> Raster Calculator` - don't confuse it with the QGIS Raster Caclulator which you will also find in the Processing Tool Box, so not the icons!).  Doing the calculation using this gives you access to many more of GDAL's options including pixel depth, NoData value.  Either of these methods should work and will take about the same time (intuitive guess) so it's your choice.

The great thing about QGIS is that it is really a "meta-GIS" as it gives you access to multiple GIS technologies under the hood.  So, there is yet a third raster calculator for you to play with that also gives you control over the pixel depth.  This is the SAGA raster calculator (also in the Processing Tool Box (go: `Processing toolbar -> SAGA -> Raster Calculus -> Raster Calculator`).

As to your final point, most of the GDAL functions under the hood can save with creation options set to a variety of compression options.  However, to do that you often need to use the command line (or 'Warp'/'Transform').  There used to be functionality to edit the GDAL command before issuing it in QGIS, but it has been removed and repeated requests to put it back have been rejected.  We never did have that with the raster calculator though.  I guess what I am saying is that QGIS is a convenience GUI for multiple GIS software packages and sometimes you may need to revert to the good ol' commandline (if you have QGIS installed, then you also have access to all the OGR/GDAL commandline modules).  BUT the good news is that you **CAN** specify these creation options if you use the GDAL Raster Calculator in Processing Tool Box (see the Advanced Parameters in the dialog box and refer to [GDAL documentation](https://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html) for what these should be).

Comment: Thank you! My first try (command adapted from Toolbox calculator) was: gdal_calc.py --calc "A>0" --format GTiff --type Byte --NoDataValue 0 -A "/home/rodrigo/prog/geofrag/geofragc/shp/wood cover change/Hansen_GFC2015_lossyear_10S_050W.tif" --A_band 1 --outfile "Hansen_10_50.tif". It worked (resulting file is byte-sized), but I still got only nan and 1 as the raster's values. I'll try the other options, but maybe someone knows why didn't I get 0 and 1.

Comment: Now I chose gdalwarp, from the previously created raster, using 0 for "No data values" (is "no data" same as "nan" here?). It finished, but the new raster still has nan and 1... :/

Comment: Yes.  Choose 'not set' for NoData (or -999 or something).